# Get next autoincrement value for datatable column?

Tags: .net

I have a datatable with an AutoIncrement column. How can I get the next increment (-1,-2,-3,...) for the column without adding a new row?

Comment: I'm just curious, why would you need to do that?

Comment: I have a Parent and a child table with one to zero or one relationship. I want to display DataGridView that will have columns for both and display all rows from the Parent, regardless of whether it has a Child, but the child elements (essentially 2 columns) still have to be editable. So, if a child already exists, an edit of a child column for an existing child will produce an edit for the database, but an edit on a non-existing child will produce an insert. I don't need to generate IDs for the inserts (since they are temporary anyway), but this may be needed for future extensions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it fits in to your design, you can always create the new row (datatable.newrow) and it will already have assigned the nextId.  It's now wasted but the row isn't committed to the table until you `AcceptChanges`.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but it accomplishes what I need it to do

Answer (score 7):

I got the solution to the problem (Not a work around) :

To get the next auto-increment value from SQLServer :

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table_name'); -- This will fetch the present auto-increment value.
```

Therefore,

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('table_name')+1; -- Next auto-increment value.
```

This will not break if rows are deleted from a table with identity and key is not consecutive.

Hope that helps.

Comment: if the table is empty and getting the `IDENT_CURRENT` will still return **1**. but it is suppose to be **0**. Since it returns 1 and incrementing it by 1 will result in 2 which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MAX function in the Select method against DataTables.

Something like (syntax might not be completely correct):

```
DataRow row = dt.Select("MAX(id)")[0];
int nextId = row["id"] + 1;
```

MSDN has a page with all the expressions you can use.  [DataColumn..::.Expression Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a datatable with an
>   AutoIncrement column.

Do you have a datatable with an AI column, or a SQL database with an AI column? If it's the SQL db that has the column, you cannot get the next value because your DataTable is disconnected. Otherwise you have to wait until you do an insert and use @@IDENTITY or a similar function.

Comment: it is a datatable with AI column

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you could do:

```
SELECT cast(last_value as integer)+cast(increment_value as integer) 
FROM sys.identity_columns 
WHERE object_id=(SELECT id FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE name='PACLogErros')
AND name='ERRCod'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the @@IDENTITY as Andrew mentioned because we cannot infer the algorithm in which SQL calculates the next identity and if you think about multiple people updating the database the identity value which you calculated will not be the same when you try to save the row to the database

Answer (score -2):

since the auto increment value is always the largest value in that column, you can just get it using max(column name) +1.

Comment: This will not work if you have added a row, then deleted it.  That said, I don't have an answer to the question.

Comment: Or if the AutoIncrementStep is different than 1.  Easy to take in to account, but still limited by daughtkom's note.

Comment: The autoincrement value is not always the largest value.  In fact it's a common pattern to use negative Ids and an increment of -1 for rows added by the client, which are replaced by values from the database when updating.